Computing a closed form representation for a Fourier series summation
I want to compute a closed form representation for the below given summation expession.
$$g_{\lambda}(\boldsymbol{x}) =  \sum\limits_{\boldsymbol{l}\in\mathbb{Z}^m} \frac{1}{1+\lambda\|\boldsymbol{l}\|_{2k}^{2k}} \cos{\left(2\pi\boldsymbol{l}\cdot\boldsymbol{x}\right)}$$
$\lambda$ is a real constant. $k,m$ are natural numbers such that $k>\frac{m}{2}$. $\boldsymbol{x}\in(0,1)^m$.
Appreciate some pointers to help me start working on this problem.

What I know, that comes close to this problem is ...
Bernoulli Polynomial ( single dimension)
$B_k(x) = -\frac{k!}{(2\pi i)^k}\sum\limits_{n\ne 0}\frac{e^{2\pi i nx}}{n^k}$
whose solution is given at the linked web page.
More work out:

As the work out in single dimension(edit added) suggests (this is only indicative and not answer as we have used integral instead of summation), its not a polynomial but an exponential, but still a closed form expression. So any closed form expression is expected, and it may no be a polynomial.
